# Show the effective web.xml generated by Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, web.xml

I know it somehow defeats part of the purpose of Spring Boot but, is there any way of seeing or printing the 'effective web.xml' of an Spring Boot app, or something similar?

Comment: What are you trying to find out? The Actuator's `/mappings` endpoint will tell you about all of your application's request mappings and all of the Servlet and Filter mappings are logged at startup.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson My resource mappings don't show in any of those two; actuator's /mappings just shows resourceHandlerMapping for /error, /**, /**/favicon.ico and /webjars/**, and they're not in the startup information either